# Html Index input tag "/" formating

Tags: html

Not so much as a problem but I was wondering why some input tags in HTML have a "/" at that end while others do not. 
Ex:
`<input name="username" id="username" />`

Comment: Possiblely answered in [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: The HTML5 spec calls these [void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) and they represent elements that cannot have any contents